# How do i block specific search words on my website from my search form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, search

i want to block certain searches from my search box....the address looks like this below:

http://domain.com/search.php?search=dog

How do i set up an array or something that blocks the search word "dog"?

```
<form id="headbar-search" action="search.php" method="GET" x-webkit-speech="x-webkit-speech">
<input type="text" name="search" id="jsid-search-input" value="<?php echo$_GET['search']; ?>" class="ui-autocomplete-input search search_input" placeholder="Search&#8230;" tabindex="1"/>
<div class="ui-widget"></div>            
</form>
```

search.php

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>

<!-- Container -->
<div id="container">
<div class="left">
<div class="pic" style="overflow:hidden; margin-top:5px;">
<div style="margin:0 0 5px 0;overflow:hidden;border:none;height:auto;">         
<div class="video-container" style="text-align: left; background: #fff;">
<h2>Search results for: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['search'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></h2>
________________________________________________________________________________________
<br><br>
<?php
if($svid) {
$squerys = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE title LIKE '%$word%' OR author LIKE '%$word%'");
while($ft = mysql_fetch_array($squerys)){
?>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<?php if($st['seo'] == 1) { ?>
<a href="./<?php echo seo($ft['title'], $ft['id']); ?>.html">
<?php }else{ ?>
<a href="./?v=<?php echo$ft['id'];?>">
<?php } ?>
<div class="image-container"><img src="<?php echo$ft['thumb_large']; ?>" width="120" height="130"></div></a></td>
<td style="padding-left:10px; vertical-align:top;"><h3>
<?php if($st['seo'] == 1) { ?>
<a href="./<?php echo seo($ft['title'], $ft['id']); ?>.html">
<?php }else{ ?>
<a href="./?v=<?php echo$ft['id'];?>">
<?php } ?>
<?php echo stripslashes($ft['title']); ?></a></h3>By: <?php echo$ft['author']; ?><br><?php echo  number_format(round($ft['views'])); ?> views</td>
</tr>
<br>
</table>
<?php
}
}else{
echo"No results found.";
}

?>

</div>
<div style="margin: 5px 0 0 0;"></div>

</div></div>


</div>

<?php include 'sidebar.php'; ?>


<div class="clear"></div>

</div>
<!-- Container -->

<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Can we have a look at search.php pretty please ?

Comment: What behavior do you expect when phrases like "IamADog" are submitted? It also has the word Dog in it.

Comment: @ThomasDavidPlat if the word is there i dont want it searched....just for the real bad words

Comment: Enjoy your sql security issue (it would be nice to check what sqli and pdo are)

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 1):

A very quick markup

```
$Naughty_Words = array ("Cat","dog");


function DetermineBanned ($Input,$Array){
    if (in_array($Input,$Array)){
        return true;
    }   
    return false;
}


var_dump(DetermineBanned("Cat",$Naughty_Words)); // Returns bool(true) 
var_dump(DetermineBanned("dd",$Naughty_Words)); // Returns bool(false) 
var_dump(DetermineBanned("CatMan",$Naughty_Words)); // Returns bool(false) 
var_dump(DetermineBanned("CatMan",$Naughty_Words)); // bool(false) 
var_dump(DetermineBanned("CatDog",$Naughty_Words)); // bool(false)
   /// Due to the lack of initial code being shown in your question, I have spotted a bug, it's up to you to decide how to make it fool proof 




//Validate with

if (DetermineBanned($_GET['Key'],$Naughty_Words) !== false){
    echo "Banned Words Detected";
    exit;

}
```

Comment: so i can add this javascript to my page and it would not search the words cat and dog?

Answer (score 1):

It has to be done in the search.php file.

Example:

```
$excluded_words = array("dog", "hello", "world");
if(in_array($_GET['search'], $excluded_words) {
     echo "Keyword not found";
}
```

Note: this is just if you pass one word only

Comment: all i have to do is add this to my search php? @Andresito

Comment: Do it before you query the database and if that's the case where the user searched for a excluded word show the message and terminate the php execution using exit();

Answer (score 1):

Put some javascript between your html and php.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="search-box" value="" placeholder="Search&#8230;"/>
    <input type="submit" onclick="search()"/>         
</form>
```

javascript

```
var badWords = ["dog"];
function search() {
    var searchStr = document.getElementById("search-box").value;
    var badWordHit = false;
    for (key in badWords) {
        if (badWords[key] == searchStr) {
            badWordHit = true;
        }
    }
    if (badWordHit) {
        alert("I ain't searchin' for no dog");
    }   else    {
        alert("searching");
        // do ajax request here
    }       
}
```